# Отображение в веб поиске сайта Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo, wordpress-плагины

использую на сайте плагин Rank Math SEO, и в настройке стоит, что должно выводится "Название страницы - название сайта",  но когда нахожу свой сайт по поиску Хром либо же Сафари, не важно, то высвечивает "Название сайта: название страницы" . Но когда нахожусь уже не посредственно на сайте, и навожу курсором на таб сверху то все нормально высвечивается "Название страницы - название сайта" . До этого использовал Yoath Seo и AIOSeo плагины. В чем может быть проблема?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Проблема в том, то ты не знаешь как работаю ПСы, но тебя они почему-то волнуют. Волнуют - изучай. А ни какой движок тут не причём. ЗЫ. "o nas" - супер просто :))))

Comment: @SeVlad какие "ПСы"? сайт на польском поэтому "o nas"

Comment: **ПС**ы- **П**оисковые **с**истемы.

Comment: Обновление мета тегов в поисковиках происходит не сразу, а когда поисковой робот проиндексирует страницу. Просто подождите :)